# converting csv to json not working as expected?

Tags: json, csv, jq, csvtojson, json2csv

I am following [this](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=27379423) article to convert csv to json. But I am not getting required output.

step 1 -

```
$ echo -e "foo,bar,quux\n1,2,3\n4,5,6\n7,8,9" > foo.csv
```

Test Step 2 -

```
$ jq -R 'split(",")' foo.csv | jq -cs
```

The output is as expected as below -

```
[["foo","bar","quux"],["1","2","3"],["4","5","6"],["7","8","9"]]
```

Next i copied the code from  [jq cookbook](https://github.com/jqlang/jq/wiki/Cookbook#convert-a-csv-file-with-headers-to-json) in to `csv2json.jq` and executed below command.

```
$ jq -cR 'split(",")' foo.csv | jq -csf csv2json.jq
```

But i am not getting expected output, I am getting below output -

```
[["foo","bar","quux"],["1","2","3"],["4","5","6"],["7","8","9"]]
```

Could someone help me fix this. Thanks in advance.

The expected or required output is -

```
[
 {
   "foo": 1,
   "bar": 2,
   "quux": 3
 },
 {
   "foo": 4,
   "bar": 5,
   "quux": 6
 },
 {
   "foo": 7,
   "bar": 8,
   "quux": 9
 }
]
```

Comment: @Fravadona - thanks for the comment. I have added the expected output to the Q.

Comment: Should you have to use jq for this? why not use other tools that can do it natively as opposed to write separate functions with jq?

Comment: @Inian, I am fine with other tools too as long as the delimiter can be changed. The delimiter for my project data is `;` but NOT `,`.  Does the other tools support this.

Answer (score 3):

I would use [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (available [here](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller/releases) for several OSs) for this task:

```bash
mlr --c2j cat foo.csv
```

Output:

```json
[
{
  "foo": 1,
  "bar": 2,
  "quux": 3
},
{
  "foo": 4,
  "bar": 5,
  "quux": 6
},
{
  "foo": 7,
  "bar": 8,
  "quux": 9
}
]
```

Comment: Exactly what I was going to propose as an alternate to jq

Comment: thanks for suggestion. In my original data file the seperator is `;` . Does miller support changing the delimiter. +1

Comment: It does: `mlr --c2j --ifs=';' cat foo.csv`

Comment: @Fravadona - thanks. Above worked for few files. But for few other files I am getting error `mlr: mlr: CSV header/data length mismatch 43 != 5 at filename abc.csv row 9.` I am sure the data is correct and not corrupted as it works with my other utils.

Comment: @CodeBot it means that the ninth record has `43` fields instead of the expected `5`. You might need to edit your CSV with a text editor to see what's wrong in there